# Is This Portion of the West Antarctic Ice Sheet Divide a Good Representation of Parallel Sided Slab on Slope Glacier

Tags: glaciology, open-data, data-analysis

I'm trying to find data that I can use to compare to the graph in Figure 6.2 on page 88 of this [source](https://ocw.hokudai.ac.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/DynamicsOfIce-2010-Note-all.pdf) which shows temperature (found from solving the parallel sided slab on slope problem) vs height above glacier base. I found data via the NSIDC database for the temperature profile of the West Antarctic Ice Sheet Divide Deep Borehole (Version 1, NSDIC-0550). The data description says that the data reports depth vs temperatures in the fluid-filled portion of the West Antarctic Ice Sheet Divide (WAIS-D) deep borehole from December 5th 2011. The spatial coverage listed for the data is Spatial Coverage:
N: -79.4676  S: -79.4676  E: -112.0865  W: -112.0865. It looks like what I want but I don't know enough about glaciology to know for sure. I know that the full WAIS cannot be modeled as a slab on slope but I was hoping maybe this portion of it could be. Additionally, I'm concerned that these measurements were taken in the part of the borehole filled with water.

Here are some links to the data that I described: [link1](https://nsidc.org/data/nsidc-0550/versions/1), [link 2](https://www.usap-dc.org/view/dataset/609550).

**Are these data a good to use for comparing the graph of temperature vs depth above surface found from the slab on slope problem?**

I was originally trying to find data for the Mendenhall Glacier because I read something about it being a reasonable comparison for the slab on slope problem but I haven't found the type of data I want yet. Would this be a better glacier to pursue for my purposes?